# How do I slow down the last few iterations of this rotation animation in CSS?

Tags: css, iteration, css-animations, duration, keyframe

```
@keyframes plusRotate

{

from {transform: rotate(0deg);}

to {transform: rotate(360deg);}

}

green
{

color: #00933B;
animation-name: p1Eat, p1FadeInC, plusRotate;
animation-delay: 10.9s, 15.3s, 21s;
animation-duration: .1s, .7s, .3s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-timing-function: linear, linear, linear;
animation-iteration-count: 1, 1, 16;
}
```

I want to make it so that around the last iteration of "plusRotate", the spinning slows.
I've tried added a separate animation with 1 iterations that has a longer duration, but then it doesn't spin at all! Basically I think it breaks somehow.

The rest of my code works fine, the only issue is in the part where I want "+" (character plus) to spin. Right now, they spin fine. The only problem is they don't slow to a stop since they are set to

```
animation-timing-function: linear
```

I could set the animation timing to any ease function, but then it eases during each iteration. I want it to continuously spin and only ease out on the last spin. Any idea how to do this?

I've already tried doing this, but then the pluses don't spin at all:

```
@keyframes plusRotate

{

from {transform: rotate(0deg);}

to {transform: rotate(360deg);}

}

@keyframes plusRotateEnd

{

from {transform: rotate(0deg);}

to {transform: rotate(360deg);}

}



green
{

color: #00933B;
animation-name: p1Eat, p1FadeInC, plusRotate, plusRotateEnd;
animation-delay: 10.9s, 15.3s, 21s, 25.8s;
animation-duration: .1s, .7s, .3s, .5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-timing-function: linear, linear, linear, ease-out;
animation-iteration-count: 1, 1, 15, 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my own post, but I've figured out a workaround.

Instead of having two animations, all I had to do was set the degree rotation to how many times I wanted it to spin - that is - 360 * numOfSpins.

Then I set the iteration count to 1 and used ease-out.

The lesson to learn here is that rotate(); can take in degrees larger than 360.

Answer (score 1):

You can use % to tell it to do animation in steps. You can even do cool fancy animation with it also.

```css
@keyframes k1 {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes k2 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    90% {
        transform: rotate(350deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.green {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color: #00933B;
    animation-name: k1;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.blue {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color: #00933B;
    animation-name: k2;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">GREEN</div>
<div class="blue">BLUE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

- Try to use clean formatting, so it's better readable.
- The `green` selector doesn't seem to be right, you probably wanted a class selector like `.green`.

Your animation seems correct, but a bit complicated. I reduced it to a simpler example and it works as expected in my opinion: [Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzjn1tLj/).

*For future questions: It's always great to provide a minimal working example of your problem for others to reproduce.*